# Why is publishing to fanout exchange also publishing to direct exchange?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, rabbitmq

I'm trying to get a RabbitMQ setup where I can choose to publish messages to services either as a fanout, or as direct. However, when I publish to the fanout exchange, I see the message delivered to all services, but also delivered in a round-robin fashion. Hence, one of the services always sees the same message twice.

Here is a full repro:

```
using System;
using RabbitMQ.Client;
using RabbitMQ.Client.Events;

namespace rabbitmq_exchanges_repro
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var hostName = "localhost";
            var factory = new ConnectionFactory
            {
                AutomaticRecoveryEnabled = true,
                HostName = hostName,
            };

            var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
            var model = connection.CreateModel();

            var serviceName = "service1";

            // This queue is for round-robin messages distributed to instances of the service with the specified service name.
            var directExchangeName = $"{serviceName}-direct";
            model.QueueDeclare(
                serviceName,
                durable: true,
                exclusive: false,
                autoDelete: false);
            model.ExchangeDeclare(
                exchange: directExchangeName,
                type: "direct",
                durable: true,
                autoDelete: false);
            model.QueueBind(
                queue: serviceName,
                exchange: directExchangeName,
                routingKey: string.Empty);

            // This is for fanout messages distributed to all services with the specified service name.
            var fanoutExchangeName = $"{serviceName}-fanout";
            model.ExchangeDeclare(
                exchange: fanoutExchangeName,
                type: "fanout",
                durable: true,
                autoDelete: false);
            var fanoutQueueName = model
                .QueueDeclare()
                .QueueName;
            model.QueueBind(
                queue: fanoutQueueName,
                exchange: fanoutExchangeName,
                routingKey: string.Empty);

            var directConsumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(model);
            var fanoutConsumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(model);
            var workItemConsumerTag = model.BasicConsume(
                queue: serviceName,
                autoAck: true,
                consumer: directConsumer);
            var fanoutConsumerTag = model.BasicConsume(
                queue: fanoutQueueName,
                autoAck: true,
                consumer: fanoutConsumer);

            directConsumer.Received += (o, e) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Received message (direct)");
            };
            fanoutConsumer.Received += (o, e) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Received message (fanout)");
            };

            Console.WriteLine("[P]ublish");
            Console.WriteLine("E[x]it");
            var exit = false;

            while (!exit)
            {
                var key = Console.ReadKey();

                switch (key.Key)
                {
                    case ConsoleKey.P:
                        model
                            .BasicPublish(
                                exchange: fanoutExchangeName,
                                routingKey: string.Empty,
                                body: new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 });
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.X:
                        exit = true;
                        break;
                }
            }

            model.BasicCancel(workItemConsumerTag);
            model.BasicCancel(fanoutConsumerTag);

            model.Close();
            model.Dispose();

            connection.Close();
            connection.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Run the above code in two separate console windows. If you press `P` in one window, you'll see that one instance outputs what I'd expected:

```
Received message (fanout)
```

But the other window outputs this:

```
Received message (fanout)
Received message (direct)
```

This is despite the fact that the `PublishBasic` call is specifying the fanout exchange name. What is going on here? How can I ensure the direct exchange isn't involved in this case?

Comment: I can't reproduce using RabbitMQ 3.7.14 and your code. I only get the "Received message (fanout)" message in each terminal window. Maybe there are old bindings in RabbitMQ? Could you reset your instance and re-try?

Comment: @LukeBakken Indeed, I removed my docker container and recreated and now it works. If you add that as an answer, I'll happily accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce using RabbitMQ 3.7.14 and your code. I only get the "Received message (fanout)" message in each terminal window. Maybe there are old bindings in RabbitMQ? You should reset your instance and re-try.